# appfuse quickstart modular full source failed testUpdateUser(

Tags: appfuse

I've followed the AppFuse QuickStart guide with modular and full source options selected. When I issue an

```
mvn install -Poracle
```

testUpdateUser throws a ...

```
.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Found shared references to a collection...model.User.roles
```

I understand that this is because the test code tries this (that's not permitted by Hibernate..)

user2.setRoles(user.getRoles());

What's the proper way to test updateUser, then?

Answer (score 0):

What version of AppFuse are you using? This should be fixed in 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is the  archetype ... I've used to generate the project ..

.... archetype -DarchetypeVersion=3.0.0

The complete statement (copied from QuickStart..)

mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-modular-spring-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=3.0.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse